# Data From A Sublist Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, sublist

How do I access the data from a sublist. The address sub tab has information that I need to read from. For example the address 2 field stored in the address book. I need to retrieve this data and pass it to a custom text box on the sales order form. I can read from sales body fields, but when I try a sublist the value comes back null. I am a little rusty, and have read the API information but still can't seem to accomplish this. I am using the internal ID of the sublist, but it does not seem to work. Obviously I am not using the right functions, but I have tried several of them with no result. Can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

```
var customer = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', 1234); //Load Customer
var itemCount = customer.getLineItemCount('addressbook') // Get line Item count
for (var i=1; i<itemCount; i++ ) {  //Loop through the lines
         var city = customer.getLineItemValue('addressbook', 'city', i); // change city to the value you want

}
```

Comment: This was a lot of help. Now I am starting to figure this out. Now my issue (which I am still trying to fix this on my own) is that whenever I change the ship to address from the drop down box the value stays the same, which I don't need. I need it to change with the ship to change. So let's say I have 2 different ship to's with a different value from the field I am pulling(let's call it city from your code). Whenever I select a different ship to the value needs to change as well. Next step is to put this value in a custom textbox, which I am currently getting an error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the sales order form there is a subtab for shipping. Within that subtab there is a field called "Ship To Select". It is a drop down box with all the address's loaded in there for that customer. When someone selects an address from that list, I need to get the value of that city.

Comment: I can grab the internal id of the ship to selected, but I am not sure how to grab the city from that internal id or if this is possible. If it is this may be a better approach.

Comment: If you do not have enough information then load the customer. Loop through each line. Get the internalId of the line and match the internalid with the internalid you have and get city from that line.

Comment: You have been a lot of help, and I think from here I can figure this out. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: The loop needs to be "i<=itemCount;"

Answer (score 0):

The address sublist is not exposed from the sales order.  If you want to know the addresses of the customer on the SO, you will need to load the customer record using nlapiLoadRecord.

Comment: I have multiple ship to addresses on each customer record. I have a value in address 2 field for all of the ship to's. When I enter a sales order, I pick a customer, and then when I click ship to select and pick a ship to, I would like to pass the value that is in address 2 field to a custom field on the sales order at the time its being entered. I am trying to explain the best I can. I have most of the code in place I just couldn't figure how to get the data from address 2 to populate to the custom text field.